# Oracle Forms: execute on canvas load

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a form with 2 canvases. The first canvas has a button that loads the second canvas when pressed. Now I want to fill some data in a list item (that is in the second canvas) when the second canvas is loaded. There's the WHEN_NEW_ITEM_INSTANCE trigger on the list item but that doesn't seem to fire when the canvas is loaded. Any idea how I could do this?

Tried searching all around but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: `WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE` is a user navigation event - it fires whenever the user navigates into a field. If they never navigate to the item, the trigger never fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your code in the button WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED if there is no other way to reach second canvas.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing right now. But if I have a second button that gets me in the same place than I have to duplicate the code. Messy.

Comment: Put the code for "initialising the second canvas" in a procedure, and call it whenever required.